# Why do Ruby people say they don't need interfaces?

Tags: ruby, oop, interface

Does ruby have something different to other OOP languages (eg: PHP) that makes interfaces useless? Does it have some kind of replacement for this?

Edit:

Some clarifications:

- In other languages (eg: PHP), you don't "need" interfaces (they are not mandatory at code level). You use them to make a contract, to improve the architecture of the software. Therefore, the affirmation 'in ruby you don't need interfaces / in other languages you need interfaces because XXX' is false.
- No, mixins are not interfaces, they are a complete different thing (PHP 5.4 implements mixins). Have you even used interfaces?
- Yes, PHP is OOP. Languages evolve, welcome to the present.

Comment: PHP is an OOP language? *chuckles*

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

Comment: PHP 5 (I think that was the version) introduced OOP design concepts to PHP but it didn't make it an "OOP" language. You can write OOP style PHP code now.

Comment: Yes, PHP is an OOP language, but not a language that should be used for comparison. 8-)

Comment: PHP is OO the same way that C++ is OO - built in such a way that OO is possible and relatively easy, but not required.

Comment: There's no direct equivalent to the interface-with-contract like you get in Java or C#, in Ruby you can determine if an object `responds_to?` method names. Or if you want the general [design by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) of `interface`s in Java/C#, there are some gems for Ruby.

Comment: Or, you just use the object as though it were what you wished it were, and let an exception be thrown if it isn't.  Most ruby code just does that.

Answer (score 16):

Well, it's a consensus that when an object is passed in Ruby it's not type-checked. Interfaces in Java and PHP are a way to affirm that an object complies to a certain contract or "type" (so something might be `Serializable`, `Authorizable`, `Sequential` and whatever else that you want).

However, in Ruby there is no formalized notion of a contract for which interfaces would fulfill some meaningful role as *interface conformance is not checked in method signatures*. See, for example, `Enumerable`. When you mix it into your object you are using its **functionality** as opposed to **declaring** that your object is `Enumerable`. The only benefit of having your object being `Enumerable` is that having defined `each(&blk)` you automatically get `map`, `select` and friends for free. You can perfectly have an object which implements all of the methods provided by `Enumerable` but does not mix in the module and it would still work.

For example, for any method in Ruby that expects an IO object you could feed in something that has *nothing* to do with an IO, and then it would explode with an error or - if you implemented your IO stub correctly - it will work just fine even though your passed object is not declared to be "IO-ish".

The idea behind that comes from the fact that objects in Ruby are not really glorified hash tables with a tag slapped onto them (which then have some extra tags that tell the interpreter or the compiler that this object has interface X therefore it can be used in context Y) but an enclosed entity responding to messages. So if an object responds to a specific message it fullfils the contract, and if it does not respond to that message - well then an error is raised.

So the absence of interfaces is compensated partially by the presence of Modules (which can contain functionality that you reach for without doing any type promises to the caller/consumer) and partially by the tradition of message-passing as opposed to typed dicts.

You should watch some presentations by Jim Weirich since he touches on the subject extensively.

Comment: Thanks, I'll watch them when I get home

Answer (score 7):

This question is kind of open-ended, but here is my take:

The purpose of an interface declaration is two things:

1. Declare to your future self or colleagues what methods this class must have
2. Declare to your computer what methods this class must have

If we take the second purpose first, Ruby source code is never compiled, so there is never an option to verify the conformance to the interface declaration and warn the developer of any failure to conform. This means that if Ruby had some built-in interface support, it wouldn't have an option to verify the conformance until runtime, where the application will crash anyway, because of the missing implementation.

So back to the first purpose. Code readability. This could make sense and a formal Ruby convention of specifying interfaces might be helpful. For now, you would probably communicate this using comments or specs or - as I would probably prefer - a declarative module inclusion. E.g.

```
module Shippable
# This is an interface module. If your class includes this module, make sure it responds to the following methods

  # Returns an integer fixnum representing weight in grams
  def weight
    raise NotImplementedError.new
  end

  # Returns an instance of the Dimension class.
  def dimensions
    raise NotImplementedError.new
  end

  # Returns true if the entity requires special handling.
  def dangerous?
    raise NotImplementedError.new
  end

  # Returns true if the entity is intended for human consumption and thereby must abide by food shipping regulations.
  def edible?
    raise NotImplementedError.new
  end

end

class Product
  include Shippable
end
```

A way of enforcing this interface would be by creating a spec that creates an instance of every class that includes the `Shippable` module, calls the four methods and expects them to not raise `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: Just a note, you don't need to explicitly instantiate the `NotImplementedErrors` using `.new` - you can just `raise NotImplementedError` and it will work.

Comment: As far as I know interfaces are good for testing purposes, so during the testing you don't need to inject the real implementation of all the services, providers etc. I know that you are able to create stubs during the testing in Ruby, but you *have to remember* then to mock all the things that should be mocked. But "having to remember" stuff in programming isn't a good thing to write software, especially when you work in a team.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a 'Ruby person', and I would like interfaces, or something like them.

Not to enforce a contract - because enforcing anything isn't very Ruby, and kind of defeats the point of a dynamic language, and anyway there's no "compilation" step to enforce it at - but to document contracts that client subclasses can choose to conform to (or not, although if they choose not to they can't complain if the code doesn't work).

When I'm faced with this problem, ie, when I'm writing a class or module I expect subclasses to provide methods for, I usually document the methods I expect subclasses to provide like this:

```
module Enumerable
  def each
    raise NotImplementedError, "Subclasses must provide this method"
  end
end
```

It's not ideal, but it's a reasonably rare case and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

As ruby is `duck-typed`, no separate interface is needed, but the objects only need to implement the common methods. Look at the "classic" example below:

```
class Duck

  def move
    "I can waddle."
  end

end

class Bird

  def move
    "I can fly."
  end

end

animals = []
animals << Duck.new
animals << Bird.new

animals.each do |animal|
  puts animal.move
end
```

In this example, the "interface" is the `move` method, which is implemented by both the `Duck` and the `Bird` class.

Comment: Here I can only see two classes with no connection between them. How is this different to any other language? In other languages you can do the same, and also add a contract (through the interface), though it's not mandatory

Comment: @Happy, the difference is that in (most) statically typed languages you _must_ use an explicit interface in order to "connect" the two classes.

Comment: @WayneConrad I know we aren't talking about advantages and disadvantages of being able to do this without an explicit interface in this thread, but it would be nice. They are not immediately apparent to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @gabe, That's a great question for programmers.stackexchange.com, if it's not already asked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because Ruby is dynamically typed whereas other languages are statically typed. The only reason you'd need to use an interface in PHP is when you use type hinting when passing objects around.

Comment: Probably a good idea to be more specific - ruby isn't just dynamically typed, it's duck typed.

Comment: While we're splitting hairs, duck typing is a specific type of dynamic typing ;)

Comment: I know, that's why I said it isn't _just_ dynamically typed ;). The reason it's relevant is because in ruby it's an object's current set of methods and properties, not its superclass or interfaces, that determine its 'type'.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is very dynamic and duck-typed. Wouldn't that make interfaces kind of useless or overkill? Interfaces force classes to have certain methods available at compile time.

Review this too:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: Interfaces are useful to make contracts between classes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by interface.

If by interface you mean a concrete object that exists in your language that you inherit from or implement then no you don't use interfaces in a language like ruby.

If you mean interface as in objects have some well documented interface then yes of course, objects still have a well documented interfaces, they have attributes and methods that you expect to be there.

I'd agree that interfaces are something that exists in your mind and the documentation and not in the code as an object.

Comment: Yes I know you don't use interfaces in Ruby, but I wanted to know why (other than the fact that the feature is not available)

Comment: @HappyDeveloper oh, I guess it wasn't obvouis. Why have them in code. It's bloat. Have the interfaces in your head, you don't need a construct in the code for this. And besides interfaces a dirty hack for languages that don't implement a proper typing system. You don't want an interface, you want a well defined type in your strictly typed language.

Comment: I can have them in my head (for a limited time) if I created the classes, but what about the developer next to me? They will just have to guess. Interfaces have a very clear role, I don't know what you mean bye 'they are a hack'. Php is dynamic too, and yet interfaces are very useful. For instance, how would you implement the Bridge pattern?

Comment: @HappyDeveloper documentation.. That's what documentation is for. Failing that, write readable code :\. I'm suggesting interfaces are a hack for languages that don't allow you to define new types. You really want to define a new type or a new struct.

Comment: So if an object that will be passed as a parameter needs to have N specific methods, I have to manually make sure they are there, by reading docs (thay may or may not be there) and checking on the class definition of that object? And after doing that, if I missed 1 method, the error will remain hidden until the application crashes? I couldn't live that way, sorry.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper ... If an object needed N specific methods you use the some kind of factory to create one of those functions. Just because we don't have interfaces doesn't mean we don't have factories. We don't re-create every bloody instance of a class by hand. Quit this nonsense.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper, please rest assured that not all Ruby devs are as hostile to ideas from other languages as Raynos seems to be. Interfaces are definitely less useful when you have dynamic typing and mixins, but I still occasionally find myself wishing I had something like them.